# Using text-overflow: ellipses in an HTML table

Tags: html, css

I must be missing something here, but why isn't my `text-overflow: ellipses` rule working correctly here?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sgj9rv5r/

```
td {
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 50px; 
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      This content should shorten to ellipses after the 50px width has been reached.
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Because [Applies to: block container elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow)

Comment: use `max-width`

Comment: Agree with CBroe, I think you can try with display: block;

Answer (score 0):

Using `max-width` as suggested by Michael Coker solves this problem.